# How to enable/disable Encryption/Decryption of Query String from Web Config?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've multiple pages that require encryption/decryption of query string. I've written the code for that and its working.

Now my requirement is to enable/disable it using web.config. Like from Web.config only, we can turn the ecryption/decryption process on or off.I don't want to go to every page and change it.

Is it possible using HTTPModules in Web.Config which will be checked from every page that tells whether to encrypt/decrypt or not?

Comment: do you want to check name of the page in your HttpModule ??

Comment: no i want to set a flag in web config which will tell that encryption is enabled or not

Comment: then simply you can use variable in web.config

Comment: Is there any other way than setting key Value pair in app settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
we can have key/value pair settings in appsettings in web.config.
  <appSettings>
    <add key="EnableURLEncryption" value="false"/>
   </appSettings>
```